# Extract data from a nested dataframe into the same record

Tags: r, dataframe, multidimensional-array, pivot-table, data-manipulation

I have this main dataframe:

```
testdataframe
       id     sensors_data
       <chr>  <list>
    1  AA     <data.frame [6 × 4]>              
    2  BB     <data.frame [6 × 4]>
```

and every dataframe of sensors_data looks like this:

```
         id type  value           status
      <chr><chr>  <dbl>           <int>
1   SN01TP  a     25.800          1
2   SN01HU  b     40.000          1
3   SN02VD  c     1.146           1
4   SN02C2  d     1270.000        1
5   SY01DS  e     31.000          1
6   TD01TP  f     22.500          1
```

I would want my main data frame to be, instead of only `sensors_data`, something like this:

```
   a      b       c      d         e       f
1  25.800 40.000  1.146  1270.000  31.000  22.500
```

I've tried unnesting the main data frame but that would create a record for each field. What I'm trying is to mutate the main data frame accessing the data inside sensors_data, but I can't figure out how.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You maximise your chance of getting a useful answer if you provide a minimum reproducible example. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help.

Comment: Please specify what your "main" data.frame is (e.g. is it the type of data.frame used in the list or is it the information of each data.frame in the list merged into one data.frame). Also, consider the use of `dput` to create the example data.frame.

Comment: @JKupzig sorry for the poorly written question, my main dataframe is "testdataframe" and inside it is the field sensors_data as well as other field (for this example only ID). I'm trying to extract the data as in the example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `purrr:map` and `tidyr::pivot_wider`, you can do this. Use `bind_rows` if you want one dataframe.

```r
df$pivoted <- df$sensors_data %>% 
  map(~ tidyr::pivot_wider(.[,c("type","value")], names_from = type))

df$pivoted
[[1]]
      a     b     c     d     e     f
1  25.8    40  1.15  1270    31  22.5

[[2]]
      a     b     c     d     e     f
1  25.8    40  1.15  1270    31  22.5

df
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  id    sensors_data pivoted         
  <chr> <list>       <list>          
1 AA    <df [6 x 4]> <tibble [1 x 6]>
2 BB    <df [6 x 4]> <tibble [1 x 6]>
```

Or, with `bind_rows` and `bind_cols`:

```r
df$sensors_data %>% 
  map(~ tidyr::pivot_wider(.[,c("type","value")], names_from = type)) %>% 
  bind_rows() %>% 
  bind_cols(df,.)

# A tibble: 2 x 8
  id    sensors_data     a     b     c     d     e     f
  <chr> <list>       <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 AA    <df [6 x 4]>  25.8    40  1.15  1270    31  22.5
2 BB    <df [6 x 4]>  25.8    40  1.15  1270    31  22.5
```

Data:

```r
df1 <- read.table(header = T, text="         id type  value           status
1   SN01TP  a     25.800          1
2   SN01HU  b     40.000          1
3   SN02VD  c     1.146           1
4   SN02C2  d     1270.000        1
5   SY01DS  e     31.000          1
6   TD01TP  f     22.500          1")

df <- tibble(id = c("AA", "BB"), sensors_data = list(df1,df1))
> df
  id    sensors_data
1 AA    <df [6 x 4]>
2 BB    <df [6 x 4]>
```

Comment: Sorry for my poorly written question, but my problem is that sensors_data is a field in the main dataframe "testdataframe", how can I map the function to the sensors_data field? should I unnest sensors_data first?

Comment: See my edit, you just have to start your request with the column where your data frames are.

Comment: Ok thanks, one last thing.. what is the .x for in the pivot longer? it doesn't work for me, it says that the object is not found

Comment: `.x` allows to call the elements that are passing by the `map` function. So here, each data frames from the `sensors_data` column. You should get the same result with `.x` being replaced by `.`. An entirely tidyverse solution would be: `map(~ .x %>% select(type,value) %>% tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = type))`

Comment: Make sure you are using map from the purrr package, e.g. by doing `purrr::map`.

Comment: Thanks! How can I save the fields on the main dataframe?

Comment: Store it in your df using `df$name_of_your_column <- `. see edit

Answer (score 1):

My favorite answer is already provided by Maël!
Here is an alternative using `lapply`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

sensors_data_sub <- lapply(sensors_data, function(x)x[,2:3])

sensors_data_sub_wide <- lapply(1:length(sensors_data_sub), 
                  function(x) (pivot_wider(sensors_data_sub[[x]], names_from = type, values_from = value)))

bind_rows(sensors_data_sub_wide)
```

```
      a     b     c     d     e     f
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1  25.8    40  1.15  1270    31  22.5
2  25.8    40  1.15  1270    31  22.5
```